# stack setup: Executable named git not found on path

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I am completely new to programming and using the command prompt.  I am trying to utilise software called Taiji using [this tutorial](https://taiji-pipeline.github.io/documentation/install.html) where I have downloaded stack into a specific folder. I have directed the command prompt into this specific folder using cd, but when I try enter stack setup it comes up with

> Executable named git not found on path:

listing several different directories/paths but not the specific folder where I have it downloaded. I apologise if this question has already been answered (I did try googling and looking up similar questions, but I had trouble understanding the solutions).

Additional note: I installed stack manually from github (commercialhaskell) instead of using their command as the command didn't work for me.

Comment: `sudo apt install git`?

Comment: It is best not to download anything by hand at this stage, but strictly use your package manager to install things that are guaranteed to work with your system. If you are using Windows, I recommend WSL (or better WSL2) for your programming task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to install the [git](https://git-scm.com/) source code management system. This is very widely used for programming in all languages, so the stack installation instructions might just assume you have it already.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, using the downloaded GIT CMD solved the issue. I was able to run 'stack setup', but still get an error during 'stack install' while constructing the build plan. In the dependencies for shelly-1.8.1: unix needed, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version is 2.7.2.2) needed due to Taiji-1.2.1 -> shelly-1.8.1. It has recommended me to add an extra-dep into stack.yaml(?) - unix 2.7.2.2@sha256:9e93f93cc5a065248120136e83a0a6d1ce93d6eb5ef2a2543f9593e93e164d24,3496 - I'm not sure what this means?

Comment: @claraina, best to ask that as a separate question!